# Copy data from table to table with batches postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I have a big table and need to copy 100 million rows from it to another.
I'm trying to do it with this script copying in batches by 1 hour interval:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
   intervalStrart TIMESTAMP := '2019-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp;
   intervalEnd TIMESTAMP;
   stopTime TIMESTAMP :='2019-07-25 00:00:00'::timestamp;
BEGIN 
WHILE (intervalStrart<=stopTime) LOOP
        intervalEnd= intervalStrart + interval '1 hour';
        RAISE NOTICE 'Time: %', intervalStrart;
        INSERT INTO marketo.activities_copy(SELECT * from marketo.activities
        WHERE activitydate>=intervalStrart and activitydate<=intervalEnd) 
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT activities_copy_pkey 
        DO NOTHING;
        intervalStrart=intervalEnd;
        END LOOP;

END $$;
```

It prints out progress

```
NOTICE:  Time: 2019-07-01 00:00:00
NOTICE:  Time: 2019-07-01 01:00:00
NOTICE:  Time: 2019-07-01 02:00:00
NOTICE:  Time: 2019-07-01 03:00:00
...
```

But when I check copy table count it is still 0. Looks like this script is performing in transaction, and commit only at the end. Why it is so?
How to make it write on each iteration?

Comment: unless the data changes are commited, one cannot see the changes on that table from a different session.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, thank you. How do I  commit the changes here? I tried to add `BEGIN;` before insert and `COMMIT;` after but get an error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 10:         BEGIN;
`

Comment: you're welcome. I don't know about the plpgsql syntax, but I guess you can try to put a commit just before `end loop` clause, after `intervalStrart=intervalEnd;`.

Comment: Issue may be there while inserting the data into the table, Try to execute the same insert script separately and check whether it is inserting correctly

Comment: @Ajay, I checked that, it insert correctly

Comment: In your script there is a condition that if there is any CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT activities_copy_pkey  then nothing should be inserted check it once

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that functions works in their own transactions by default. And in postgres 10 there is not way to commit changes in the middle, although we can use `EXCEPTION` keyword to handle errors. In postgres 11 there are new feature procedures which support commits in it.

Comment: so what was the final solution?